# UICollectionView item deletion raises exception

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

Inside of `UICollectionViewController` this is deletion code.

```
- (IBAction)tapRead:(id)sender
{
    if (self.editing)
    {
        BookCell *cell = (BookCell*)[[sender superview] superview];
        NSArray *arr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:cell.ipath, nil];

        _totalCount--;
        NSLog(@"total: %d", _totalCount);

        [self.collectionView deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:arr];
    }
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return _totalCount;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath; {
    BookCell *cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"BookCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.ipath = indexPath;

    if (self.editing) {
        [cell engageEditMode];
    }
    else
    {
        [cell exitEditMode];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Now when I delete items always from the end, it works just fine. However, when I delete some from the beginning, some from the middle, at some point I got an exception when I try to delete the last element:

```
'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to delete item 24 from section 0 which only contains 20 items before the update'
```

I am not sure how to debug this...

Comment: My guess is that you haven't deleted the object from the array.Please delete the object from the array and reload the collection view

Comment: @vin see my answer, assumed the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the problem is the same as the one that arises when you delete an item from a UITableView without updating the datasource, thus causing the exception. Try the following:

```
[self.datasource removeObjectAtIndex:iPath.row];
//... delete the row from the collectionView.
```

Comment: I do not have datasource as itself for now. Just simulating it using `_totalCount`.

Comment: @Pablo, I see. Have you tried NSLogging the indexPath to make sure it's correct and refers to the indexPath of the row you'd like to delete?

Comment: the problem might be here: `cell.ipath = indexPath`. I think it's totally wrong way to set index path of each cell and during deletion it will overwrite correct index path. There must be better way of knowing which cell button press referring...